# Why does my HTML table shrink images from left to right?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I made a simple HTML table, filled it with placeholder images, and spaced them with a background color. This is what I get:

[image]

Compare the rightmost image to the left... then notice how each image gets smaller. Very odd.

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #C6C6C6;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.examplesite.com/pholder.png" />
    </td>
    <td style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.examplesite.com/pholder.png" />
    </td>
    <td style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.examplesite.com/pholder.png" />
    </td>
    <td style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.examplesite.com/pholder.png" />
    </td>
    <td style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"></td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.examplesite.com/pholder.png" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, I space the table with a margin and empty columns. I think that may be the cause, but I'm not sure why or how to fix it while keeping the neat visual appearance. How do I fix this?

Note: The site is also mobile-responsive and has to scale images automatically, so setting a fixed width/height will not work for me.

Comment: I just tried it, works as expected. What is it you want to achieve?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I do not have a good answer to your exact question but I can tell you using a table for layout is a very bad practice especially if you want to make the site responsive. Tables are for tabular data display.

Using divs and css with media queries will assure that your layout is consistent. Sure it will take a bit more but there is a lot of good material out there on how to do it.

**====EDIT ====**

To fix the issue at hand as well you can add a width to the td. It will keep them the same size if you know how many elements will be displayed. In the current table you have 5 so

```
<tr>
    <td width="20%">image</td>
    <td width="20%">image</td>
    <td width="20%">image</td>
    <td width="20%">image</td>
    <td width="20%">image</td>
</tr>
```

Tables try and space things depending on the content. It leads to the end cells getting squished.

Comment: Thanks, defining the width % fixed it.

Comment: No problem. I will lead with answer and then give warning for now on I suppose.

Comment: Yes, that would be wise. Although I appreciate the warning and did wind up using divs instead, even after fixing the tables; it was more suited as a comment.